# Getting JAR file from S3 using Flink Kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I'm experimenting with the new Flink Kubernetes operator and I've been able to do pretty much everything that I need besides one thing: getting a JAR file from the S3 file system.

### Context

I have a Flink application running in a EKS cluster in AWS and have all the information saved in a S3 buckets. Things like savepoints, checkpoints, high availability and JARs files are all stored there.

I've been able to save the savepoints, checkpoints and high availability information in the bucket, but when trying to get the JAR file from the same bucket I get the error:
`Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugins: flink-s3-fs-hadoop, flink-s3-fs-presto.`

I was able to get to [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg48176.html), but I wasn't able to get the resource fetcher to work correctly. Also the solution is not ideal and I was searching for a more direct approach.

### Deployment files

Here's the files that I'm deploying in the cluster:

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: flink-deployment
spec:
  podTemplate:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: pod-template
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          env:
            - name: ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS
              value: flink-s3-fs-presto-1.15.3.jar;flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.3.jar
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /flink-data
              name: flink-volume
      volumes:
        - name: flink-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /tmp
            type: Directory
  image: flink:1.15
  flinkVersion: v1_15
  flinkConfiguration:
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3://kubernetes-operator/checkpoints
    state.savepoints.dir: s3://kubernetes-operator/savepoints
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
    high-availability.storageDir: s3://kubernetes-operator/ha
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  serviceAccount: flink
```

session-job.yml

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkSessionJob
metadata:
  name: flink-session-job
spec:
  deploymentName: flink-deployment
  job:
    jarURI: s3://kubernetes-operator/savepoints/flink.jar
    parallelism: 3
    upgradeMode: savepoint
    savepointTriggerNonce: 0
```

The Flink Kubernetes operator version that I'm using is 1.3.1

Is there anything that I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download of the jar happens in flink-kubernetes-operator pod. So, when you apply FlinkSessionJob, the fink-operator would recognize the Crd and will try to download the jar from jarUri location and construct a JobGraph and submit the sessionJob to JobDeployment. Flink Kubernetes Operator will also have flink running inside it to build a JobGraph.
So, You will have to add **flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.3.jar** in location **/opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/** inside flink-kubernetes-operator

You can add the jar either by extending the ghcr.io/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator image, curl the jar and copy it to plugins location

or

You can write an initContainer which will download the jar to a volume and mount that volume

```
    volumes:
    - name: s3-plugin
      emptyDir: { }
    initContainers:
    - name: busybox
      image: busybox:latest
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop
        name: s3-plugin
    containers:
    - image: 'ghcr.io/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator:95128bf'
      name: flink-kubernetes-operator
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop
        name: s3-plugin
```

Also, if you are using serviceAccount for S3 authentication, give below config in flinkConfig

```
fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have not tested extending the flink kubernetes operator, but what you've said makes perfect sense, so I'm inclined to believe that it works. However that solution does not seem very scalable in terms of maintanability, so I've ended up creating a custom image that downloads the JAR file to the volume mount.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking this up in future, here's what I did that helped.

Depending on your version of the k8s operator, you may now have a [`postStart`](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/pull/609) helm chart value. As of this writing, that version is yet unreleased, but if you read the source code, all it does is inject a place in the operator deployment for you to run arbitrary code.

So I went into edit the k8s deployment:`kubectl edit deployment/flink-kubernetes-operator`, and added it there. Note that you might need to set the plugin folder env var. Obviously if you run `helm install` / `helm upgrade`, again, this will get erased, but hopefully they release the new helm chart with the `postStart` config soon.

```yaml
# This is the values.yml file for the operator.
operatorPod:
  env:
  - name: FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR
    value: /opt/flink/plugins
```

```yaml
# This is the deployment definition of the operator. i.e. when you do kubectl edit. 
# Look for the main container spec
# ... truncated 
    containers:
      - command:
        - /docker-entrypoint.sh
        - operator
        env:
        - name: OPERATOR_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        # there might be more things in here...
        image: ghcr.io/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator:be07be7
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        # add this following section, making sure you choose the right version for you.
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - 'mkdir $FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR/flink-s3-fs-hadoop && curl -H "Accept: application/zip"
                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-s3-fs-hadoop/1.15.4/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.4.jar
                --output $FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR/flink-s3-fs-hadoop/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.4.jar'
# ... truncated
```

Then, in your FlinkDeployment yaml, all you have to do is find the main container and add these 2 env vars. Flink will automagically copy the plugin(s) (semicolon or ' ' separated) into the folder so you dont have to run anything custom.

```yaml
# truncated
        - name: flink-main-container
            env:
            - name: ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS
              value: flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.4.jar
            - name: "FLINK_PLUGINS_DIR"
              value: "/opt/flink/plugins"
# truncated
```

Not entirely sure why this works with the Flink image but not on the Operator one. Also not sure why there aren't clearer docs around this.

Unlike the previous comments, you *should not* add `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider` to your config. The plugin has a default list of credentials providers that it will try based on your configuration environment. I use IAM roles, making the flink serviceaccount a trusted entity in MyCustomS3FlinkWritePolicy so I don't have to put AWS secrets in EKS.