# Use Flink Kubernetes Operator and setup FlinkSessionJob with S3 on Minio

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am trying to use Flink Kubernetes operator to run an application with multiple jobs in a session cluster. My issue is that I need to use s3 storage for the checkpointing and savepoints. I use a local k3d installation that also has minio pods setup for the s3 storage.

Therefore I did create a custom image based on the https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/releases/tag/release-1.4.0 and essentially added on the plugins directory under `/opt/flink` the **s3-fs-hadoop** and **s3-fs-presto** directories copying inside them the corresponding jars from the `/opt/flink/opt` directory of the image.

I proceeded with using that custom image for creating **FlinkDeployment** resource and I was able to see that deployment seems to successfully start and enable the s3 plugins. Initial logs for FlinkDeployment can been seen below

```
    Enabling required built-in plugins
    Linking flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.1.jar to plugin directory
    Linking1 flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.1 to plugin directory
    Successfully enabled flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.1.jar
    Linking flink-s3-fs-presto-1.16.1.jar to plugin directory
    Linking1 flink-s3-fs-presto-1.16.1 to plugin directory
    Successfully enabled flink-s3-fs-presto-1.16.1.jar
    sed: couldn't open temporary file /opt/flink/conf/sedNLg8lR: Read-only file system
    sed: couldn't open temporary file /opt/flink/conf/sed6vCEtB: Read-only file system
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 74: /opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml: Read-only file system
    /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 90: /opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml.tmp: Read-only file system
    Starting kubernetes-session as a console application on host my-flink-cluster-5967dc856b-rlznq
```

Also the **FlinkDeployment** kubernetes manifest used is the following

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: my-flink-cluster
spec:
  image: k3d-test-app-registry:5050/flink-kube-s3:v1 
  flinkVersion: v1_16
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"
    kubernetes.operator.periodic.savepoint.interval: 1h
    state.savepoints.dir: "s3://state/minio-service:9000"
    state.checkpoints.dir: "s3://state/minio-service:9000"
    s3.endpoint: http://minio-service:9000
    s3.path.style.access: "true"
    s3.access-key: ****
    s3.secret-key: ****
    metrics.reporters: prom
    metrics.reporter.prom.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 1
   podTemplate:
    spec:
     containers:
      - name: flink-main-container 
        env:
        - name: FLINK_PARALLELISM  
          value: "3"  
        - name: CHECKPOINT_DIR  
          value: "s3://state/minio-service:9000"  
        - name: ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS
          value: flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.1.jar;flink-s3-fs-presto-1.16.1.jar
```

Unfortunately when I try to deploy a test **FlinkSessionJob** from examples provided by Flink, based on the manifest below

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkSessionJob
metadata:
  name: my-flink-job
spec:
  deploymentName: my-flink-cluster
  flinkConfiguration:
    kubernetes.operator.periodic.savepoint.interval: 1h
    state.savepoints.dir: "s3://state/minio-service:9000"
    state.checkpoints.dir: "s3://state/minio-service:9000"
    s3.endpoint: http://minio-service:9000
    s3.path.style.access: "true"
    s3.access-key: ****
    s3.secret-key: ****
  job:
    jarURI: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-examples-streaming_2.12/1.16.1/flink-examples-streaming_2.12-1.16.1-TopSpeedWindowing.jar
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: stateless
```

I get the following error in the logs of the pod for FlinkDeployment

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to create checkpoint storage at checkpoint coordinator side.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:337) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:245) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.enableCheckpointing(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:511) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.java:317) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:156) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:361) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.<init>(SchedulerBase.java:206) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.<init>(DefaultScheduler.java:134) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:152) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:119) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:369) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:346) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:123) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:95) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the followin
g plugin(s): flink-s3-fs-hadoop, flink-s3-fs-presto. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-
stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/plugins/ for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems
. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.
```

That seems to point on the missing jars for s3 from the plugins, though when I connect with the interactive terminal in the FlinkDeployment pod I can see that s3 jars exist in the plugins directory.

I have also experimented with the proposed approach based on the following question on stackoverflow which uses s3
([Getting JAR file from S3 using Flink Kubernetes operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338015/getting-jar-file-from-s3-using-flink-kubernetes-operator))
but unfortunately the results were the same.

Can you point to me what am I doing wrong or what I miss? Has anybody used *FlinkSessionJob with s3* and can you point me to a relevant example ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but you only need one of the two libraries:

From the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/):

> For most use cases, you may use one of our flink-s3-fs-hadoop and flink-s3-fs-presto.

You do not need to add additional Haddo

> Flink provides two file systems to talk to Amazon S3, flink-s3-fs-presto and flink-s3-fs-hadoop. Both implementations are self-contained with no dependency footprint.